# django email does not work and don't sent email

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-email

I am following this tutorial
the aim to verify email after users register to the system. here is the code.

serializers.py

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)

    default_error_messages = {
        'username': 'The username should only contain alphanumeric characters'}

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'password']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        username = attrs.get('username', '')

        if not username.isalnum():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                self.default_error_messages)
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

my view.py

```
class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        user_data = serializer.data
        user = User.objects.get(email=user_data['email'])
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user).access_token
        current_site = get_current_site(request).domain
        relativeLink = reverse('email-verify')
        absurl = 'http://' + current_site + relativeLink + "?token=" + str(token)
        email_body = 'Hi ' + user.username + \
                     ' Use the link below to verify your email \n' + absurl

        data = {
            'email_body': email_body ,
            'to_email': user.email ,
            'email_subject' : 'Verify your email'
            }

        Util.send_email(data)
        return Response(user_data , status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

my utils.py

```
class EmailThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, email):
        self.email = email
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.email.send()


class Util:
    @staticmethod
    def send_email(data):
        email = EmailMessage(
            subject=data['email_subject'], body=data['email_body'] , to=[data['to_email']])
        EmailThread(email).start()
```

and the settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOSTS = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER = "talibdaryabi@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "**********"
```

when I test the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/register/`
by providing

```
{
    "email":"talibacademic@gmail.com",
    "username":"talibacademic",
    "password":"aahg786ahg786"
}
```

I get the

```
{
    "email": "talibacademic@gmail.com",
    "username": "talibacademic"
}
```

which means the user was created but can't receive email.

can anyone help me with the issue, I also have allowed Less secure app access setting for talibdaryabi@gmail.com account.

Comment: Did you check in spams?

Comment: yes, I didn't get

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py, you need to define [`EMAIL_BACKEND`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/),

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = youremail
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ****
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**Note:**

It's better to store your credentials in [environment variables](https://dev.to/biplov/handling-passwords-and-secret-keys-using-environment-variables-2ei0).

Comment: I think the problem was with EMAIL_HOST which I wrote EMAIL_HOSTS, in both cases where I added the email_backend or not I got the email.  thank you Avishka

Comment: oops didn't saw that 'S'